# PrimeNG DataList pagination breaks when page 3 is created

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, datalist, primeng

*August 23 Update: Migrated to PrimeNG Beta 13. Still having this problem. Any advise on how to debug this?*

*August 15 Update: Just migrated my project to Angular2 RC5. The problem with the data list is still present.*

I am having a strange problem with [datalist](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datalist) pagination (using PrimeNG Beta 12, but had the same problem in Beta 11). The problem is most likely in my code as I use the datalist somewhere else without any issues.

My component (page) contains one button and one datalist. The datalist has one paginator at the bottom and the datalist's `rows` attribute is set to **5**.

The data source for the datalist is an array of objects called votes (a part of a larger object). Initially, votes array is empty. The button opens a PrimeNG Dialog that contains a simple form. Upon submission of the form, a new vote object is created and pushed in the votes array.

For the first 10 votes, the data list works as expected. When vote 6 is added, the datalist correctly creates new page (#2) containing data from vote 6. Page 1 contains 5 rows with data from votes 1-5.

When votes 7-10 are added, they also correctly create new rows on Page 2. However, when vote 11 is added to the array, the data that corresponds to vote 11 is added to the end of page 2 of the datalist as row **6**(!) **and** also to the new page 3 as row 1.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

> Template

```
<p-dataList [value]="providerData.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex]?.votes" [paginator]="true" rows="5" [responsive]="true">
      <header>
        <div>
          <h1>
            {{providerData?.reportCards[providerData?.selectedReportCardIndex]?.reportCardYear}} {{providerData.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].reportCardDataSource.reportCardSourceName}}
          </h1>
          <h2>Congressional Votes ({{providerData.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex]?.votes?.length}})</h2>
        </div>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-plus" (click)="onAddVoteButtonClicked()" label="Add" title="Add vote"></button>
      </header>
      <template let-vote>
        <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" style="padding:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5;">
          <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil" (click)="onEditVoteButtonClick(vote)" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Edit vote"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-2" style="text-align: center">
              <span title="chamber">{{vote.chamber | legislativeBodyToStringPipe}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-2" style="text-align: center">
              <span title="roll cal number">{{vote.rollCallNumber}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-4" style="text-align: center">
              <span title="preferred action / action weight">{{vote.preferredAction | voteActionToStringPipe}} / {{vote.actionWeight | actionWeightToStringPipe}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
              <i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="onDeleteVoteButtonClick(vote)" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Delete vote"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </p-dataList>

    <p-dialog header="Add Vote" [(visible)]="displayAddVoteDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" width="400">
      <create-vote-form [reportCardYear]="providerData.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].reportCardYear" [reportCardName]="providerData.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].reportCardDataSource.reportCardSourceName"
        [voteCount]="providerData.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].votes.length" [voteWeightOptions]="voteWeightItems"
        [preferredVotePositionOptions]="preferredPositionItems" [chamberOptions]="chamberItems" (voteCreated)=onVoteCreated($event)
        (formCancelled)=onCreateVoteFormCancelled() [errorMessages]="createVoteError"></create-vote-form>
    </p-dialog>

    <p-dialog header="Confirm Deletion" [(visible)]="displayVoteDeleteConfirmation" modal="modal" showEffect="fade">
      <p>
        Delete the following vote and all related data (<strong>NO undo</strong>)?
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>{{providerData?.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex]?.votes[selectedVoteIndex]?.chamber | legislativeBodyToStringPipe}}</strong><br/>
        <strong>{{providerData?.reportCards[providerData.selectedReportCardIndex]?.votes[selectedVoteIndex]?.rollCallNumber}}</strong>
      </p>
      <footer>
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
          <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-close" (click)="onVoteDeleteConfirmButtonClick(false)" label="No"></button>
          <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-check" (click)="onVoteDeleteConfirmButtonClick(true)" label="Yes"></button>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </p-dialog>
```

> Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Button, SelectItem, Message, Dialog, DataList, Column, Header, Footer } from 'primeng/primeng';

import {ProviderData, DataService, ReportCardVote,
    ActionWeightToStringPipe, LegislativeBodyToStringPipe, VoteActionToStringPipe,
    DUPLICATE_REPORT_CARD_VOTE_MESSAGE} from '../shared/index';
import {CreateVoteFormComponent} from './create-vote-form.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'vote-data-entry',
    templateUrl: 'vote-data-entry.component.html',
    directives: [Button, DataList, Header, Footer, Column, Dialog, CreateVoteFormComponent],
    pipes: [ActionWeightToStringPipe, LegislativeBodyToStringPipe, VoteActionToStringPipe,]
})
export class VoteDataEntryComponent implements OnInit {

    public createVoteError: Message[] = [];
    private chamberItems: SelectItem[];
    private preferredPositionItems: SelectItem[];
    private voteWeightItems: SelectItem[];
    private providerData: ProviderData = new ProviderData();
    private displayAddVoteDialog: boolean = false;
    private selectedVoteIndex: number = -1;
    private displayVoteDeleteConfirmation: boolean = false;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    // Returns the index of the report card vote in the selected reportCard that has the same chamber
    // and rollCallNumber, or -1 if there is no match.
    indexOf(selectedVote: ReportCardVote): number {
        return this.providerData.reportCards[this.providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].votes.findIndex(x =>
            x.chamber === selectedVote.chamber && x.rollCallNumber === selectedVote.rollCallNumber);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.chamberItems = this.dataService.getChamberItems();
        this.preferredPositionItems = this.dataService.getpPreferredPositionItems();
        this.providerData = this.dataService.getProviderData();
        this.voteWeightItems = this.dataService.getActionWeightItems();
    }

    onAddVoteButtonClicked() {
        this.createVoteError = [];
        this.displayAddVoteDialog = true;
    }

    onCreateVoteFormCancelled() {
        this.displayAddVoteDialog = false;
    }

    onDeleteVoteButtonClick(vote: ReportCardVote) {
        this.selectedVoteIndex = this.indexOf(vote);
        this.displayVoteDeleteConfirmation = true;
    }

    onVoteDeleteConfirmButtonClick(isDeleteOk: boolean) {
        if (isDeleteOk) {
            this.providerData.reportCards[this.providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].votes.splice(this.selectedVoteIndex, 1);

            // store updated reportCards in local storage
            this.dataService.storeProviderData(this.providerData);
        }
        this.displayVoteDeleteConfirmation = false;
    }

    onVoteCreated(newVote: ReportCardVote) {
        if (newVote) {
            if (this.indexOf(newVote) === -1) {
                this.providerData.reportCards[this.providerData.selectedReportCardIndex].votes.push(newVote);

                // store updated reportCards in local storage
                this.dataService.storeProviderData(this.providerData);
            } else {
                // duplicate vote
                this.createVoteError = [];
                this.createVoteError.push(DUPLICATE_REPORT_CARD_VOTE_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Page 2 (after 11th vote added, should have 5 rows!)

[image: DataList Page 2]

> Page 3 (after 11th vote added)

[image: DataList Page 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a typo in the first line of the template. `rows="5"` should have been `[rows]="5"`.